# Implementation of NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, abstraction

How is a NSArray implemented, is it similar to `std::vector`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not similar to `std::vector`.

The implementation details are opaque beyond that it is tuned to the most common uses found on the platform.

[This should provide some insight.](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/)

Answer (score 2):

depending on the details you're after, you may be interested in reading the implementation of CFArray, which is available in CFLite (or CF-Lite).

CFLite is hosted by Apple, it is an open implementation of a subset of CoreFoundation.framework. i am also assuming you are aware of the NSArray<->CFArray relation.

Comment: Careful with that source... the implementations contained within the source may vary significantly from what is shipped with the system.